# How to set struct tag for Entity A might have B in GORM and make create and preload works automatically

Tags: go, go-gorm

Consider I have `BaseNotification` and `ExtendedNotification` structs.

For some notifications they use `base_notificaion` table only yet some of them will save some extra data into `extended_notificaion`.

How to setup struct tag in these two structs so that when I run

```
db.Create(&entendedNotification) // or something else
```

GORM will know it need to insert a new tuple into `extended_notification` if needed(for example either it is not `nil` or fields are filled)

And when I call

```
db.Preload(`ExtendedNotification`).Find(&notifications)
```

it will grab all necessary entities accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure A's primary key id is a foreign key in B, use like this

```golang
type A struct{
    Id int `gorm:"column:id"`
    B []B `gorm:"column:b;ForeignKey:Aid"`
}
type B struct{
    Aid int 
}
```

if not, I suggest using

```golang
func (a *A) AfterFind()error{
    return db.Model(&B{}).Find(&a.B).Error
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but A and B is one to zero or one relationship. I think `AfterFind` is quite likely the ultimate solution